# Play multiple sounds at the same time in python

Tags: python, audio, interactive

I have been looking into a way to play sounds from a list of samples, and I found some modules that can do this.

I am using **AudioLazy** module to play the sound using the following script:

```
from audiolazy import AudioIO

sound = Somelist
with AudioIO(True) as player:
  player.play(sound, rate=44100)
```

The problem with this code is that it stop the whole application till the sound stop playing and I can't play multiple sound at the same time.

My program is interactive so what I want is to be able to play multiple sound at the same time,So for instance I can run this script which will play a 5 second sound then at the second 2 I can play a 5 second sound again.

And I don't want the whole program to stop till the sound finish playing.

Comment: Is your application a gui? If so what kind of?

Comment: Well It is more of a script, I am making an extension to a program called blender, but yah it has a GUI.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simpler solution using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/).

Using `overlay` function of `AudioSegment`  module, you can very easily `superimpose` multiple audio on to each other.

Here is a working code to combine three audio files. Using same concept you can combine multiple audio onto each other.

More on `overlay` function [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py)

`pydub` supports multiple audio formats as well.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

audio1 = AudioSegment.from_file("chunk1.wav") #your first audio file
audio2 = AudioSegment.from_file("chunk2.wav") #your second audio file
audio3 = AudioSegment.from_file("chunk3.wav") #your third audio file

mixed = audio1.overlay(audio2)          #combine , superimpose audio files
mixed1  = mixed.overlay(audio3)          #Further combine , superimpose audio files
#If you need to save mixed file
mixed1.export("mixed.wav", format='wav') #export mixed  audio file
play(mixed1)                             #play mixed audio file
```

---

**Here are updates as per our discussions.**
First we create 44KHz signal and save to `sound.wav`
Next Read wave file and save signal to text file
Then create three variations of input signal to test overlay.
Original signal has `dtype int16`
Then we create three audio segments
then mix/overlay as above.
`wav` signal data is stored in `test.txt`

**Working Modified Code**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import wave, struct, math


#Create 44KHz signal and save to 'sound.wav'
sampleRate = 44100.0 # hertz
duration = 1.0       # seconds
frequency = 440.0    # hertz

wavef = wave.open('sound.wav','w')
wavef.setnchannels(1) # mono
wavef.setsampwidth(2) 
wavef.setframerate(sampleRate)

for i in range(int(duration * sampleRate)):
    value = int(32767.0*math.cos(frequency*math.pi*float(i)/float(sampleRate)))
    data = struct.pack('<h', value)
    wavef.writeframesraw( data )

wavef.writeframes('')
wavef.close()

#Read wave file and save signal to text file
rate, signal = read("sound.wav")

np.savetxt('test.txt', signal, delimiter=',')   # X is an array


#load wav data from text file
wavedata1 = np.loadtxt("test.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False, dtype=np.int16)

#Create variation of signal
wavedata2 = np.loadtxt("test.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False, dtype=np.int32)

#Create variation of signal
wavedata3 = np.loadtxt("test.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False, dtype=np.float16)

#create first audio segment
audio_segment1 = AudioSegment( 
    wavedata1.tobytes(), 
    frame_rate=rate,
    sample_width=2, 
    channels=1
)

#create second audio segment
audio_segment2 = AudioSegment( 
    wavedata2.tobytes(), 
    frame_rate=rate,
    sample_width=2, 
    channels=1
)

#create third audio segment
audio_segment3 = AudioSegment( 
    wavedata3.tobytes(), 
    frame_rate=rate,
    sample_width=2, 
    channels=1
)

# Play audio (requires ffplay, or pyaudio):
play(audio_segment1)
play(audio_segment2)
play(audio_segment3)

#Mix three audio segments
mixed1 = audio_segment1.overlay(audio_segment2)          #combine , superimpose audio files
mixed2  = mixed1.overlay(audio_segment3)          #Further combine , superimpose audio files
#If you need to save mixed file
mixed2.export("mixed.wav", format='wav') #export mixed  audio file
play(mixed2)                             #play mixed audio file
```

Comment: My script read samples (floats) and not wave files,can his be done using pydud?

Comment: What kind of samples? can you post a sizable example? It may be possible to generate audio-segment from samples, frame-rate  and sample_width.
See `audiosegment.py` for details

Comment: A sample like [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0] A sine wave for instance.

Comment: See modifications above. I saved wav file to text and created audio_segment from there. This mimics your sample. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) to do this.

```
import pyaudio 
import wave
sound1 = wave.open("/path/to/sound1", 'rb')
sound2 = wave.open("/path/to/sound2", 'rb')

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data1 = sound1.readframes(frame_count)
    data2 = sound2.readframes(frame_count)
    decodeddata1 = numpy.fromstring(data1, numpy.int16)
    decodeddata2 = numpy.fromstring(data2, numpy.int16)
    newdata = (decodeddata1 * 0.5 + decodeddata2* 0.5).astype(numpy.int16)
    return (newdata.tostring(), pyaudio.paContinue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple threads will solve your problem :

```
import threading
from audiolazy import AudioIO

sound = Somelist
with AudioIO(True) as player:
  t = threading.Thread(target=player.play, args=(sound,), kwargs={'rate':44100})
  t.start()
```

Comment: It still not working, Putting in mind that this script will be converted into a function,I mean the whole script will be inside a function.This is how the program I am programming for works. will this have an impact?

Comment: No it should be fine.
How so it's not working? Do you have any error?

Comment: The whole programe freeze while the sound is playing,and if I tried to play 2 sounds at once, python just play the first sound wait till it finish then play the next sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had to play a bit sound over a song according  a time list (for practicing some footwork)

```
import pygame as pg
import time

pg.mixer.init()
pg.init()

a1Note = pg.mixer.Sound("/mnt/ramfs/tmprypk5djp.wav")
a2Note = pg.mixer.Sound("/mnt/ramfs/tone.wav")

pg.mixer.set_num_channels(50)
beat_list = beat_times.tolist()

elapsed_time = 0
start_time = time.time()

a1Note.play()

while len(beat_list)>0: 
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    minTime = min(beat_list)
    if elapsed_time > minTime:
        print(f'elapsed_time {elapsed_time} -- minTime  {minTime}')
        a2Note.play()
        minTime = beat_list.pop(0)
```