# Play Multiple sound files simultaneously through raspberry pi, preferably using python

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make an instrument on the raspberry pi but it's my first time using one so it's a bit tricky. In the program that I'm writing for this instrument I'm having trouble executing multiple sounds at once, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there are some similar Q&A's on stack already:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830968/6253693

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644525/6253693

I also just tried a third implementation that works, see code below:

```
import simpleaudio as sa
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("Downloads/sample1.wav")
wave_obj2 = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("Downloads/sample2.wav")
wave_obj.play()
wave_obj2.play()
```

Generally good practice to do some searching before asking a repeated question (I recently made the same mistake though so no worries.)